# PHP-EWS Error: Couldn't bind to service

Tags: php, soap, exchangewebservices

I'm getting "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't bind to service in" when I try to make any call using php-ews.  I've copied the services.wsdl, messages.xsd, and types.xsd files from my Exchange instance into my local ews/wsdl directory and the service is clearly defined in it and I'm using the correct version (ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2007_SP1).  Any ideas?

Comment: One thing is whenever debugging SOAP using a WSDL turn off caching.  `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);`  Can you post the WSDL,  specifically the `definitions` part?  Error message is pretty clear.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for the tip on caching, I made sure it was off.  The WSDL is over 1K lines long so here's a link.  http://pastebin.com/aXEeL0XT

Comment: Hmm, any https?  Maybe look at `local_cert` param of SoapClient.  I mean generic answer to the error is: "you need to define the service element of the [WSDL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/webservess/chapter/ch06.html)"...  I'd start by viewing the WSDL in the browser and trying to click through to the URIs.  Hopefully you'll find not that does not resolve.  Tried any validators?  Sorry I can't offer more help.

Answer (score 10):

Since you've downloaded the services.wsdl from your exchange server, you'll have to modify it.

Before the closing tag (wsdl:definitions) add:

```
    ...
    <wsdl:service name="ExchangeServices">
      <wsdl:port name="ExchangeServicePort" binding="tns:ExchangeServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://path.to.your.exchange.server/EWS/Exchange.asmx" />
      </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service> 

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Genius.  This should be the answer.