# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't bind to service

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

By initializing `SoapClient` for submitting data (to one of the) Dutch pension funds it's returning the error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't bind to service.

Unfortunately, I can't get sufficient technical support from there site. Currently, I'm testing on the test WSDL. My server IP address needed to be whitelisted after that it seemed at least to read the WSDL. Also, It seems that the username/password is correct.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the error could mean? I added a location URL but I'm not 100% sure that it's correct. Could it be this? Maybe other suggestions?

```
$UPA_wsdl =  "https://upa-ws-swo.tkppensioen.nl/ws/upa.wsdl";
$UPA_un = "TSTUPAEXT3";   
$UPA_pw = "wE{vyRVKe";                              

$params = array (
    'login' => $UPA_un,
    'password' => $UPA_pw,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
    'verifypeer' => false, 
    'verifyhost' => false, 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 
    'trace' => 1, 
    'exceptions' => 1, 
    'features'=>SOAP_WAIT_ONE_WAY_CALLS,
    'location' => "http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS"
);

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($UPA_wsdl, $params);   
} catch (SoapFault $client) {
    echo $client->getMessage();

    OutputXML($client->__getLastRequest(), true);   
}
```

The wsdl of the services look like this;

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="UPAServiceO" targetNamespace="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>-- Versie informatie --</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation>Versie 2019:</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation>
- nieuwe versie gemaakt; Nu UTF-8 encoding, verder geen wijzigingen
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation>Versie 2018:</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation> - nieuwe versie gemaakt; verder niks</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation>Versie 2017:</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation>
- IdBer als optioneel veld toegevoegd bij OntvangBerichtAlsZIP
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation>Versie 0.95: september 2015:</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:documentation> - Initiele versie</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS">
<xs:element name="ZendBerichtAlsZIP">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="idLcr" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="idBer" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="berichtZIP" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ZendBerichtAlsZIPResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="ZendBerichtAlsZIPResult" nillable="false" type="tns:StatusResponseType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="StatusResponseType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Status" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Foutmelding" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="StatusResponseType" nillable="false" type="tns:StatusResponseType"/>
<xs:element name="OntvangBerichtAlsZIP">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="idLcr" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idBer" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="OntvangBerichtAlsZIPResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="OntvangBerichtAlsZIPResult" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="UPAWebService_ZendBerichtAlsZIP_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part element="tns:ZendBerichtAlsZIP" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UPAWebService_ZendBerichtAlsZIP_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part element="tns:ZendBerichtAlsZIPResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UPAWebService_OntvangBerichtAlsZIP_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part element="tns:OntvangBerichtAlsZIP" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UPAWebService_OntvangBerichtAlsZIP_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part element="tns:OntvangBerichtAlsZIPResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="UPAWebService">
<wsdl:operation name="ZendBerichtAlsZIP">
<wsdl:input message="tns:UPAWebService_ZendBerichtAlsZIP_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/ZendBerichtAlsZIP"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:UPAWebService_ZendBerichtAlsZIP_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/ZendBerichtAlsZIPResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="OntvangBerichtAlsZIP">
<wsdl:input message="tns:UPAWebService_OntvangBerichtAlsZIP_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/OntvangBerichtAlsZIP"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:UPAWebService_OntvangBerichtAlsZIP_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/OntvangBerichtAlsZIPResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_UPAWebService" type="tns:UPAWebService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ZendBerichtAlsZIP">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/ZendBerichtAlsZIP" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="OntvangBerichtAlsZIP">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/OntvangBerichtAlsZIP" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the same as this one: [PHP-EWS Error: Couldn't bind to service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431575/php-ews-error-couldnt-bind-to-service)

You need to add a wsdl:service definition to your WSDL.